# Splitting a string by delimiter if characters exist either side of delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

In JavaScript how can I split a string by delimiter only if the delimiter has a character (non-numeric) on either side of it? Can this be accomplished with via RegEx?

```
var str = 'this-is-hyphenated - this isn't';
```

Should result in an array: this | is | hyphenated - this isn't

Comment: Why there is a separation after `hyphenated`?

Comment: Is it acceptable to you that ` - this isnt` and whatever follows until the next valid delimiter would be all one item?

Comment: It's an example. I only want to split the string on hyphens that have a character on either side of it.

Comment: Something like `\b-\b|(?=-)` would do the job. The only problem is with an input like `this is a _-_ test`. See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qS8mA4)

Comment: @HamZa—that fails the "non–numeric" criterion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a less RegEx version

```
var str      = 'this-is-hyphenated - this isn\'t',
    chrRegEx = /[a-z]/i;

var result = str.split("-").reduce(function(result, current) {
    var previous = result[result.length - 1];

    if (!previous) {
        return result.concat(current);
    }

    if (chrRegEx.test(previous[previous.length-1]) && chrRegEx.test(current[0])){
        result = result.concat(current);
    } else {
        result[result.length - 1] += "-" + current;
    }

    return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
# [ 'this', 'is', 'hyphenated - this isn\'t' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

> how can I split a string by delimiter only if the delimiter has a character (non-numeric) on either side of it?

Given the "non–numeric" criterion, you can't use `\b` (end of word) flag as it will match digits in words (e.g. foo2 is seen as one word, not a word followed by '2').

You can do it in two steps using replace with a string that is extremely unlikely to occur (say `&&&&`) and capture groups:

```
s.replace(/([a-z])-([a-z])/ig,'$1&&&&$2').split('&&&&')
```

however that may not be what you want.